# Eclipse rcp application loads plugins from the IDE?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

I have an RCP application which works fine but problems occured once I tried to develop plugins for it.

What I did:

1. Create a working RCP application.
2. Setup an eclipse IDE for developing plugins for my RCP application: I added all the plugins of my rcp application into the plugin folder of the IDE and adjusted the launch configuration so it starts my application.
3. When running the application it starts up and I see all the functionallity of my RCP application BUT I also see a lot unneccessary information from the eclipse IDE. The about tab for example is stuffed with like 8 different icons. Also the ClearCase Plugin I'm using for developing is part of the menu in my RCP application.

**EDIT :** Menu entries that I don't want:

1. Window->ShowView->Other (Here all the views that are available for the IDE are shown)
2. Window->Preferences (Here all the preferences of the eclipse IDE are shown).
3. Help->Report Bug or Enhancment (I don't want this entry at all).
4. Help->Software Update (I don't want this entry at all).
5. Help->About Dialog (Contain's a lot information about the eclipse IDE which I don't need at all).
6. Toollbar->Create new visual classes (I want to remove this button).
7. Toolbar->Open Task  (I want to remove this button).

How do I get ride of the plugin/eclispe IDE specific menu entries and the other eclispe specific information?
Why are they appearing only when developing plugins for my rcp and not when developing the rcp itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `.product` file and export your RCP application instead of put them into your Eclipse Plugins folder and changing the initialization config.

Then you export your product and the result is your RCP application, that follows the same structure of Eclipse, but the plugins folder contains only the plugins you define in the dependencies of your product.

You should the following FAQs and tutorial to start with Products

- [Vogella: Eclipse Products and Deployment Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html)
- [Eclipse FAQ: What is and Eclipse product?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_Eclipse_product%3F)
- [Eclipse FAQ: How do I create an Eclipse product?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_Eclipse_product%3F)

Comment: Thank you, your answer will be helpful once I finde the time to give it another shot!